# How to echo variable without losing space in a for loop?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, echo

```
$ cat testfile
first line mark apple
second line not banana
third line mark pear
```

I want to for loop each line of the file. If it contains `mark` then show the whole line without losing space.

but if my code as below, it turns the space into return:

```
for i in `cat testfile | grep mark`; do
    echo $i
done
```

output is

```
first
line
mark
apple
third
line
mark
pear
```

if use printf

```
for i in `cat testfile | grep mark`; do
    printf $i
done
```

output is

```
firstlinemarkapplethirdlinemarkpear
```

how can I get the output as below:

```
first line mark apple
third line mark pear
```

Comment: grep mark testfile

Comment: I was about to suggest `for i in "$(grep mark testfile)" ; do echo "$i" ; done`, but it sets `$i` to the entire multi-line output of the `grep` command rather than iterating by lines.

Answer (score 2):

This should be OK:

```
grep mark testfile
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

```
grep mark testfile
```

No loop needed. And no [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

---

But if you want to understand why your loop doesn't work, it's because you're looping over each *word* in grep's output. To loop over each *line* you need to use `read`:

```
cat testfile | grep mark | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

or

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done <(cat testfile | grep mark)
```

Actually, to be completely safe, we should add `IFS=` and `read -r` to preserve all whitespace and backslashes properly.

```
cat testfile | grep mark | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

This is a lot of unnecessary code, though. Reading each line just to spit them back out? Better to just omit the whole loop.

Comment: That's perfect. But in addition, after the grep, my script need to loop the result, and pick-up the last word into a function to test it's pattern, if it's match, then print the whole line. If that's the case should I go with for i in `grep mark testfile`; do? I'm afraid in this way, it breaks up again?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your reply, after convert into grep pattern file, the script is below, let me know if it's the appropriate one:

```
grep pattern file | while read line; do
    ip=`echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 8`
    fqdn=`echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 6`
    grepcidr -v -f /root/collect/china_routes.txt <(echo $ip) >/dev/null
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        grep $fqdn fqdnfile || echo $fqdn >> /root/collect/fqdn
    fi
done
```

The above is trying see if 'pattern' show up in any line of file, then it pick-up the eighth field as ip, sixth field as fqdn(since the line is separated by space); then it will check whether $ip is in the cidr scope by grepcidr, if it's not within the scope(-v), then to check whether the $fqdn already exist in fqdnfile file, if it's not in the file, then echo the $fqdn into that file

The file itself looks like below:

```
Oct 11 20:19:05 dnsmasq[30593]: reply api.weibo.com is 180.149.135.176
Oct 11 20:19:05 dnsmasq[30593]: reply api.weibo.com is 180.149.135.230
Oct 11 20:19:06 dnsmasq[30593]: query[A] sina.com from 180.169.158.178
Oct 11 20:19:06 dnsmasq[30593]: forwarded sina.com to 114.114.114.114
Oct 11 20:19:06 dnsmasq[30593]: reply sina.com is 66.102.251.33
Oct 11 20:19:06 dnsmasq[30593]: query[PTR] 74.103.225.116.in-addr.arpa from 127.0.0.1
Oct 11 20:19:06 dnsmasq[30593]: cached 116.225.103.74 is NXDOMAIN-IPv4
```